# There was a getting an ad response Admob Error

Tags: java, android, admob

I want to update one source code from old `GoogleAds SDK` to new `Google Play Service Library`, but there is a problem. Everytime I got this error:

There was a problem getting an ad response.

> ErrorCode: 0
>
> Failed to load ad:0

This is code from playactivty:

```
public String BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID;

AdRequest adRequest;

private void LoadAds()
{
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    this.BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID = getResources().getString(R.string.admob_id);
    // Create the adView
    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID);

    // Add the adView to it
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .build();
//  AdRequest.setTesting(true);
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);   
}
```

And from layout.xml

```
    </RelativeLayout>

  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        
        android:id="@+id/adView" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
</LinearLayout>
```

What I was doing wrong there? Can not find issue, and trust me, I was read all SOF posts about that error :)

Thank you very much!

Edit:

Original code:

`PlayActivity.java`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
    LoadConfigParams();
    LoadSharedPreferences();
    LoadResources();
    LoadListeners();        
    LoadStage(mCurStage);
    LoadAds();
        

}

    private void LoadAds()
{
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutAdmob);

    // Create the adView
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, getResources().getString(R.string.admob_id));

    // Add the adView to it
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    request.setTesting(true);
    adView.loadAd(request); 
}
```

`activity_play.xml` (only last LinearLayout code, above that is RelativeLayout).

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutAdmob" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you checked your admob account? what medium are you testing on? is that the only error response you get? do you have add blockers? elaborate

Comment: I use same pub ID from Admob which I use in another live app, so I think Admob is OK? I think there is a problem with code, because I build this code as puzzle, from different source codes :)) Beginner :)

Comment: okay sir, are you trying to show one add or two adds and you want it in a relative layout right? give me what you want so i re-write it for you

Comment: I just update original post with original source code, which use old AdmobSDK. Now I just want to rewrite code to work with Google Play Service and showing Admob banner in <LinearLayout> (bottom of the screen).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of creating an `Admob` add by `java`or `xml`, the easiest way-(even though both are easy) is `xml`.Also if you use `SMART_BANNER` you are going to get adds of different sizes, and if the size does not fit/match the remaining screen space your`RelativeLayout` has left for `LinearLayout` your add will not show. so i will assume you have taken care of that

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutAdmob" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
      android:id="@+id/myaddview"
      ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id">
</LinearLayout>
```

then in your `loadAds()`

```
AdView adView = findViewById(R.id.myaddview); //add the cast
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
.build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

thats all you need check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29864713/adrequest-builder-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type/29867029#29867029) to know what to import and double check your permissions

Comment: Thank you very much @Elltz for your help. But I still geting error :(

`W/Ads(16465): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
I/dalvikvm(16465): Could not find method android.webkit.WebSettings.setMixedContentMode, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.u.h.<init>
W/dalvikvm(16465): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3060: Landroid/webkit/WebSettings;.setMixedContentMode (I)V
 D/dalvikvm(16465): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x004a
W/Ads(16465): Failed to load ad: 0`

Comment: you are using the lastes version of google play services right? are you testing it on a real device? what is the name of the package name of your app? pls tell me, i am conjuring that, try clearing the dat on your play service on the device and also the error has to do with the webkit, it was targeting a method that was added in api 21 and you are not testing in api 21 hence that error, can i see your manifest sir? @Karnak

Comment: yes, I`m using Google Play Service Rev.23. I`m testing all things on my Galaxy S4. This package isn`t published on Google Play yet. Here is my manifest file http://pastebin.com/HGfH21ux .Thank you so much Elltz, hard to find that kind people! :)

Comment: hmm, i do not think i can have solid solution but try this go to your google play services app in settings and clear the data, and re-try again, if it does not solve it try a sample app with a different package name and see if it works, please try and let me know @Karnak

Comment: I just found there is a new update for Androd Support Library and also new API22. Update all things (not Play Service) and this start˙s to work :) Thank you very very much Elltz!

Comment: oh Thank good lord, im glad you are able to solve it, what a hard 4 days of struggle, but its all good, im glad to be of help even though i did not really help, happy coding sir, wish you good times.@Karnak

Answer (score 0):

MobileAds.initialize(this);

works for me