# AdRequest Builder cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, admob

I finished developing a game for Android using a slightly modified version of the framework at http://www.kilobolt.com/unit-4-android-game-development.html. Then I followed this tutorial:https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start and successfully added an ad but not on my main activity as this framework does not have a .xml file for the main activity (surface view in pure java code). However, I want ads to appear on the main activity too since that contains 95% of the game. I managed to successfully add a test view (button) on the surfaceview using an online tutorial but when I changed the button to an AdView I got this error:

"AdRequest.Builder cannot be resolved to a type" in

`AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();`.

Can someone tell me what could cause this error? Eclipse accepted the exact same code in my other activity on the same project but not here. I have made the necessary imports.

```
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    appContext = this.getApplicationContext();
    mainLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    adLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"); // google test id
    //AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    adLayout.setLayoutParams(lp2);
    adLayout.addView(adView);
    lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);  
    lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    adView.setLayoutParams(lp1); 

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    boolean isPortrait = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
    int frameBufferWidth = isPortrait ? 800 : 1280;
    int frameBufferHeight = isPortrait ? 1280 : 800;
    Bitmap frameBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameBufferWidth, frameBufferHeight, Config.RGB_565);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    float scaleX = (float) frameBufferWidth / metrics.widthPixels;
    float scaleY = (float) frameBufferHeight / metrics.heightPixels;

    GameScreen.deviceWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    GameScreen.deviceHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

    prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("AppPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefsExist = prefs.contains("showValueAddition");
    loadDefaultSettings();

    renderView = new AndroidFastRenderView(this, frameBuffer);
    graphics = new AndroidGraphics(getAssets(), frameBuffer);
    fileIO = new AndroidFileIO(this);
    audio = new AndroidAudio(this);
    input = new AndroidInput(this, renderView, scaleX, scaleY);
    screen = getInitScreen(prefs);

    mainLayout.addView(renderView);
    mainLayout.addView(adLayout);
    setContentView(mainLayout);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you post that portion of the code Sir?

Comment: @Elltz Updated the first post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this `import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;`

Comment: glad it did Sir, happy codding then @Steyiak

Answer (score 0):

Use This Library

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
```