# android - AdMob ads without firebase

Tags: android, admob

I want to integrate AdMob ads to my new android project, but I get an error when the app tries to load the ad. `There was a problem getting an ad response.ErrorCode: 0` and `Failed to load ad: 0`. I don't want to integrate firebase

I added the play-services to my gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
}
```

This to my manifest.xml:

```
</application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

This to my activity_main.xml:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

And in my code I added:

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you go here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup you'll find all the Google Play services you can use including ads. Add this dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have AdMob without FireBase.
This is working code.

Gradle:

```
 dependencies {
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"               ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

and in my code

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);        
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXXX");
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: The emulator still shows the same error. Maybe it's an emulator fault?

Comment: On a real device the ad does not show up either. Do you know what the problem might be?

Comment: One possibility is that it may take a few hours to see ad if you make new ad unit id.

Comment: I made it a few days ago - but it should be visible on real device anyway, shouldn't it? Do you have another idea?

Comment: Did you add these library? import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;  Also, http://stackoverflow.com/a/29884790/7303462 a comment says update Androd Support Library and API ?

Comment: Actually yes - I don't get an error anymore, but the ads doesn't show up

Comment: `E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbva', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.zzgl.zze` That's what my logcat says - might be something wrong with the play services importing?